# Problems with ä in a bibliography link

Tags: bibliographies

I have problems putting the ä character inside a reference link. In fact, when I click on it in the .pdf file that I obtain, the link sends me to the top of the first page, instead that to the reference voice.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\lipsum
\cite{ä0000}
\cite{word}


\begin{thebibliography} {20}
    \small
    \bibitem [ä0000] {ä0000} description1
    \bibitem [word] {word} description2
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The why do you use ä? Replace it by e.g. ae -- as the key is not printed it doesn't matter.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: if it's possible I would like to maintain ä; otherwise I'll follow your suggestion

Comment: Is there something that's forcing you to use a diacritic in the arguments of `\cite` and `\bibitem`? Changing the two instances of `{ä0000}` to `{a0000}` (or some other string that doesn't contain non-ASCII characters) eliminates the problem immediately. Incidentally, I assume you're compiling your document with pdfLaTeX; if you can switch to LuaLaTeX, you can keep the `ä` character and still get the correct hyperlink behavior...

Comment: @Mico: see my comment to UlrikeFischer

Comment: @Andrea - Is switching to LuaLaTeX an option for you? As I mentioned in my earlier comment, that will let you keep using non-ASCII characters. Separately, it would be helpful if you explained your reason for wanting to have non-ASCII characters in the arguments of `\cite` and `\bibitem` in the first place. Neither Ulrike nor I can so far see a compelling reason for doing so.

Comment: @Mico: How can I compile with LuaLaTeX with TeXStudio? I add the comment `% !TeX program = lualatex` at the beginning of my .tex document, but I obtain the error: File `ltluatex.tex' not found. \input{ltluatex}. Suggestion?

Comment: @Andrea: Well you already saw that it doesn't work. Don't use umlauts and other non-ascii-chars in labels and cites and bibkeys (in the curly braces -- the ä in the bracket [ä0000] is ok).

Comment: @Andrea - TeXstudio is just a front-end. Which TeX distribution do you use?

Comment: @Mico: - MikTeX  -

Comment: @Andrea: While lualatex would allow Umlauts in this case your document as it is is not suitable for lualatex. You will have to remove inputenc, load fontspec and perhaps do other adaptions to your document. I doubt very much that it is easier than exchanging ä with ae.

Answer (score 3):

With pdflatex you shouldn't use non-ascii chars in labels and cite keys. Replace the ä with ae:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\lipsum
\cite{ae0000}
\cite{word}


\begin{thebibliography} {20}
    \small
    \bibitem [ä0000] {ae0000} description1
    \bibitem [word] {word} description2
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

With lualatex it would be possible to use the ä, but lualatex would need other changes in your document (no inputenc, fontspec instead of fontenc, and probably more in your real document). I doubt very much that a change to lualatex is easier than exchanging ä with ae.

Comment: It's (also) bibtex that can't use non-7bit characters. Bibtex8 can use full Ascii. Biblatex should be utf8 compatible.

Comment: @PhilipPirrip: The example of the question doesn't use bibtex, but a manually written bibliography.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I thought that manually written bibliography  was used just to simplify things (the MWE).